# Overlay 2 pdf pages with opacity 50%

Tags: python, image, pdf

I am trying to overlay the pages of two PDF files with 50% opacity so that I can observe better the differences between some pages that are almost the same. I am using the fitz library from PyMuPDF.
I have this code:

```
# Importing required modules
import fitz # PyMuPDF library for working with PDF files

# Opening the input PDF files
pdf1 = fitz.open("file1.pdf")
pdf2 = fitz.open("file2.pdf")

# Creating a new PDF document for output
output_pdf = fitz.open()

# Looping through each page of the PDF files
for i in range(pdf1.page_count):
    # Loading the pages
    page1 = pdf1.load_page(i)
    page2 = pdf2.load_page(i)

    # Creating a new PDF document for each page pair
    temp_pdf = fitz.open()

    # Inserting the first PDF page into the temporary document
    temp_pdf.insert_pdf(pdf1, from_page=i, to_page=i)

    # Showing the second PDF page on top of the first one with 50% opacity
    temp_pdf[0].show_pdf_page(page1.rect, pdf2, pno=i, overlay=True, alpha=0.5)

    # Inserting the temporary document into the output document
    output_pdf.insert_pdf(temp_pdf)

# Saving the output document as output.pdf
output_pdf.save("output.pdf")

# Closing the input and output PDF files
pdf1.close()
pdf2.close()
output_pdf.close()
```

It overlays the pages of the both pdf files but it doesn't make the content of the pages transparent.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to convert your PDF to images, then use PIL `Image.blend()` [method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.blend), then resave that as a PDF.

Here is one implementation, assuming that your pdfs are `path1.pdf` and `path2.pdf` and that the new pdf should be saved at `out.pdf`

```py
from itertools import zip_longest                                                       
from pdf2image import convert_from_path                                                 
from PIL import Image                                                                   
                                                                                         
pages = convert_from_path("path1.pdf")                                                  
pages2 = convert_from_path("path2.pdf")                                                 
                                                                                         
RESOLUTION = 300 # DPI                                                                  
                                                                                        
new_pages = []                                                                          
                                                                                        
for p1, p2 in zip_longest(pages, pages2):                                               
    # Get the nth page of each pdf together                                             
    if p1 is None:                                                                      
        new_pages.append(p2)                                                            
    elif p2 is None:                                                                    
       new_pages.append(p1)                                                            
    else:                                                                               
        new_pages.append(Image.blend(p1, p2, alpha=0.5))                                
                                                                                        
new_pages[0].save(                                                                      
    "out.pdf", save_all=True, append_images=new_pages[1:], resolution=RESOLUTION        
)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Er... is right: the second PDF's pages must be converted to transparent images, which then can be used to overlay the first PDF' pages. You page loop could look like this:

```py
for i in range(pdf1.page_count):
    # Loading the pages
    page1 = pdf1[i]
    page2 = pdf2[i]
    pix = page2.get_pixmap(alpha=True)
    # compute alpha values corresponding to 30% opacity
    alphas = bytes([80 for k in range(pix.width * pix.height)])
    pix.set_alphas(alphas)
    page1.insert_image(page1.rect, pixmap=pix)
pdf1.ez_save("compared.pdf")
```